# How to display the desired view after traversing to some level with NavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Is there any way to display the home screen or (first view controller) after i traversed to some levels with  the NavigationController

Answer (score 2):

YES, try this

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

All the Best.